# Bug with Javascript's JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data":"{\"json\":\"rocks\"}"}'));
```

gives error (tested on Firefox and Chrome's console). Is this a bug with JSON.parse? Same decodes well when tested with PHP.

```
print_r(json_decode('{"data":"{\"json\":\"rocks\"}"}', true));
```

Comment: Note: I tried to explain what the problem is, but have a look at Oleg's answer for how you should structure your data.

Comment: Yeah. But the quotes were intentional. You answered it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This string is processed differently in PHP and JS, i.e. you get different results.

The only escapes sequences in single quoted strings in PHP are `\\` and `\'`. All others are outputted literally, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

In JS on the other hand, if a string contains an invalid escape sequence, [the backslash is discarded](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4) (`CV` means character value):

> - The CV of *CharacterEscapeSequence :: NonEscapeCharacter* is the CV of the *NonEscapeCharacter*.
> - The CV of *NonEscapeCharacter :: SourceCharacter* but not *EscapeCharacter* or *LineTerminator* is the *SourceCharacter* character itself.

*The quote might not be helpful by itself, but if you follow the link and have a look at the grammar, it should become clear.*

---

So in PHP the string will literally contain `\"` while in JS it will only contains `"`, which makes it invalid JSON:

```
{"data":"{"json":"rocks"}"}
```

If you want to create a literal backslash in JS, you have to escape it:

```
'{"data":"{\\"json\\":\\"rocks\\"}"}'
```

Answer (score 4):

To have a literal backslash in a string literal,you need `\\`.

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data":"{\\"json\\":\\"rocks\\"}"}'));
```

This will successfully escape the inner quotation marks for the JSON processing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data":"{\\"json\\":\\"rocks\\"}"}'));​
```

Answer (score 2):

object with one or more then **'\'** wont return Object by **JSON.parser**, It will return the string again with skipping one **'\'**.
You can do parse again and again until all **'\'** skipped.

myobj = {\"json\":\"rocks\"}

myobj = {\\"json\\":\\"rocks\\"}

Following lines worked for me

remove backslash

```
while(typeof myobj == 'string'){
       myobj = JSON.parse(myobj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to escape double quotes inside single quotes and you have two extra quotes in your input around inner object, just

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data":{"json":"rocks"}}'));
```

is enough.

Comment: Yeah I know that is the right way. The quotes were intentional.