# parseJSON fails, while json_decode works

Tags: jquery, json

I've been struggling with this for some time, I have a stringified JSON object stored in DB, once I retrieve it I decode it with both PHP and jQuery, PHP works fine, jQuery fails, heres the code

```
var data = $.parseJSON('{"page_name":"Test page","page_title":"Test title","site":"0","page_url":"http:\/\/saulius.epickitdev.com\/test-page","page_type":"1","bg_type":"gradient","background_img_url":"","fill_bg_color":"","background_color":"","background_gradient_top":"5194c4","background_gradient_bottom":"000000","video_type":"yt","youtube_video_url":"","youtube_video_start_from":"","mp4_video_url":"","webm_video_url":"","ogg_video_url":"","width_type":"fixed","width_padding":"10","layout_color":"cc25cc","border_size":"3","border_color":"5a7de6","container_position":"middle","container_position_left":"","container_position_right":"","meta_title":"mtest","meta_description":"mdesc","meta_keyword":"mkey","fb_title":"ftitle","fb_description":"fdesc","header_script":{"1":"<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"h1\">","2":"<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"h2\">"},"footer_script":[""],"redirect_url":"","exit_message":""}');
        console.log(data);
```

Now it tells me that the error is:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 766 of the JSON data

Which would be at the '=' of:

```
"<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"h1\">"
```

Anyone have any clues? I tried different parsers and i'm completely stuck with this!

Comment: Chrome wins the error message duel btw "SyntaxError: Unexpected token k"

Comment: @Prinzhorn Yeah that took me back to the days where I would simply get, "There was an error"

Comment: Read here, it's exaplained in accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655517/bug-with-javascripts-json-parse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to double encode the `\` characters in the String to `\\`.

```
var s = '{"page_name":"Test page","page_title":"Test title","site":"0","page_url":"http://saulius.epickitdev.com/test-page","page_type":"1","bg_type":"gradient","background_img_url":"","fill_bg_color":"","background_color":"","background_gradient_top":"5194c4","background_gradient_bottom":"000000","video_type":"yt","youtube_video_url":"","youtube_video_start_from":"","mp4_video_url":"","webm_video_url":"","ogg_video_url":"","width_type":"fixed","width_padding":"10","layout_color":"cc25cc","border_size":"3","border_color":"5a7de6","container_position":"middle","container_position_left":"","container_position_right":"","meta_title":"mtest","meta_description":"mdesc","meta_keyword":"mkey","fb_title":"ftitle","fb_description":"fdesc","header_script":{"1":"<meta name=\\"keywords\\" content=\\"h1\\">","2":"<meta name=\\"keywords\\" content=\\"h2\\">"},"footer_script":[""],"redirect_url":"","exit_message":""}'
$.parseJSON(s)
```

This is because they are escapes inside a string, inside a string.

The top level string is the whole value, so unwrapping one level of escaping leads to this,

```
{"1":"<meta name="keywords" content="h1">"} #Invalid JSON
```

This is invalid because the quotes in the value are no longer escaped, since the top level JavaScript string *unwrapped* them. When that string literal is read in by the JavaScript interpreter, all the `\` characters are unwrapped one level, which means that `\"` becomes just `"`. Then the JSON string needs to be processed, but it is no longer valid, since the quotes that you intended to escape, are now unescaped (In reality they were never *really* escaped, they just seemed that way.) When you use single quotes, you don't need to escape `"`, but you can always escape **anything**, if it isn't a special character it just does nothing.

So in order to have the quotes still be escaped after the top level string is processed, you need to escape the `\` itself.

```
var s = '{"1":"<meta name=\\"keywords\\" content=\\"h1\\">"}'
console.log(s) //'{"1":"<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"h1\">"}'
$.parseJSON(s)
```

Comment: Why? Their escaped already? Any best way solution to do this?

Comment: It is perfectly escaped for JSON, but you are using it as a string in JS. If you would read the string from file or ajax it would parse just fine. The problem is that you just copied it into your JS file without proper string escaping.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a ton of time

Comment: fyi - you don't actually need to escape the forward slashes in the url in this string. `http://saulius.epickitdev.com/test-page` parses correctly as is. Good answer though!

Comment: @Novocaine You are right. The OP had them in the string and I didn't notice them. When I saw the issue, I just did a string replace on ``\`` to ``\\`` and ended up double escaping those as well. I have updated the answer to remove those escapes. Thanks for pointing that out!